# When updating a post of a custom post type its shows an error Forbidden You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/post.php on this server

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, posts

I just created a custom post type and some posts inside it. but now during updating some post-it show an error "Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/post.php on this server."

and there are no issues while creating new posts. only while updating existing posts:(

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's because of ModSecurity ,
Just disable ModSecurity on your Cpanel .
If you don't have access to this option, contact your host provider and say that you want to disable this option .

Answer (score 0):

I was getting crazy with this too. After to do a lot of things i found the solution.
Just disable ModSecurity on your Cpanel.
If you don’t have access to this option, contact your host provider and say that you want to disable this option temporarily or forever.
Hope that works for y’all!